# Are techniques from Warioware: D.I.Y actually useable in creating an actual game?

Tags: software-engineering

In a game called **Warioware: D.I.Y,** it teaches you how to create *minigames* with certain forms of AI. Can I use the techniques shown in this game to actually **develop** an advanced game?

Comment: You should explain in more detail what those techniques actually are. That way, people who haven't actually played the game themselves could answer.

Comment: And additionally edit question title to clearly show it concern Warioware game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, WarioWare DIY provides you with a very high-level *rules* engine - each rule (called an Assembly Instruction, or AI) consists of a trigger and a series of actions that are performed when the trigger is... well, triggered.

Rules are in other words statements of the form "When A occurs, B happens", and they define the *basic gameplay* of a game. Obviously, A and B can be significantly more complex in a "real" game than in WarioWare DIY, but the principle still applies.

There are many different game development tools out there, and different engines provide different layers of abstraction in how you define the gameplay.

Something like [Multimedia Fusion 2](http://www.clickteam.com/multimedia-fusion-2) works on a similar level to WarioWare DIY by having you define triggers and actions - but of course, there are limitations to that approach, since not everything is easily expressable in the framework provided by the engine. Using a more general engine like [Unity](http://unity3d.com), where you write code to express the gameplay, offers more flexibility - but you also have to handle more things on your own, so it's a tradeoff.

By only having these ~5-second microgames, WarioWare DIY is able to apply a very high abstraction level. This makes it very easy to dive in, and this allows you to get some practice in actually *seeing* the rules that make up the game, and *converting* them to something the program can understand. With enough clever thinking, you can even do some very non-obvious things.

In that sense, then *yes*, WarioWare DIY can teach you some skills that will help you to develop more advanced games. *However*, you still need to do a lot of thinking to convert those rules into something meaningful, and there will almost surely be a lot of things in that process that don't make any sense in a microgame - WarioWare DIY isn't going to help you much with those parts - and you also have to remember that some of the tricks you can do in DIY might not be appropriate or even necessary in a "full" game.